# How to get database structure in MySQL via query?

Tags: mysql

Is it possible to somehow get structure of MySQL database, or just some table with simple query?

Or is there another way, how can I do it?

Answer (score 312, accepted):

I think that what you're after is [`DESCRIBE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/describe.html)

```
DESCRIBE table;
```

You can also use [`SHOW TABLES`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/show-tables.html)

```
SHOW TABLES;
```

to get a list of the tables in your database.

Comment: To target specific database use:  `SHOW TABLES FROM database_name`

Answer (score 130):

To get the whole database structure as a set of [CREATE TABLE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/create-table.html) statements, use [mysqldump](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysqldump.html):

```
mysqldump database_name --compact --no-data
```

For single tables, add the table name after db name in mysqldump. You get the same results with SQL and [SHOW CREATE TABLE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/show-create-table.html):

```
SHOW CREATE TABLE table;
```

Or [DESCRIBE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/describe.html) if you prefer a column listing:

```
DESCRIBE table;
```

Comment: `show create table` was exactly what I was looking for. Thanks!

Comment: this is not the solution but i'm gratefull because I didn't know this function exists and is great!

Comment: @AriWaisberg what do you mean? This is THE SOLUTION

Answer (score 53):

Take a look at the `INFORMATION_SCHEMA`.`TABLES` table. It contains metadata about all your tables.

Example:

```
SELECT * FROM `INFORMATION_SCHEMA`.`TABLES`
WHERE TABLE_NAME LIKE 'table1'
```

The advantage of this over other methods is that you can easily use queries like the one above as subqueries in your other queries.

Comment: Isn't it that it should be `information_schema`.`columns` (using `columns` table instead of `tables`? Because `tables` doesn't contain any info on which types are the the table columns

Comment: 2nd advantage is that information schema is loaded in memory at server start so no hdd reading neccesary

Comment: yes, definitely should be COLUMS rather than TABLES!  That works a treat!

Answer (score 37):

using this:

```
SHOW CREATE TABLE `users`;
```

will give you the [DDL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_Definition_Language) for that table

```
DESCRIBE `users`
```

will list the columns in that table

Comment: soulmerge, sure it's a DDL statement for that table

Comment: Yes, it's a statement in a DDL, but a C function is not by itself C. C is a language, a function in a C program is a construct within that language.

Comment: @soulmerge, I'm a pedant too, but I think you're wrong here: "The French for 'thanks' is 'merci'" is quite an acceptable English sentence (no less than "The French WORD for", etc), and this generalizes to "The {{language name}} for {{thing to express}}" such as "The DDL for this table".

"A C function is not by itself C" is the same as saying "A French word is not by itself French": well it's not ALL of French of course, but saying "'Au revoir' is French" is hardly objectionable (as obviously it means it's PART OF French, not ALL OF French!-).

Comment: @soulmerge. Yes, definitely a reason to vote down... Enjoy!

Comment: dafuqq is going on here

Answer (score 22):

```
SELECT *
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'test' AND TABLE_NAME ='products';
```

where `Table_schema` is database name

Comment: is there a way to select information schema. columns -  tables from particular db ?

Comment: I used this query on my end
`SELECT TABLE_NAME, COLUMN_NAME, DATA_TYPE, IS_NULLABLE, COLUMN_COMMENT
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'my_db_name' AND TABLE_NAME ='users'; `

Answer (score 17):

That's the [SHOW CREATE TABLE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/show-create-table.html) query. You can query the [SCHEMA TABLES](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/information-schema.html), too.

```
SHOW CREATE TABLE YourTableName;
```

Answer (score 12):

A variation of the first answer that I found useful

Open your command prompt and enter (you dont have to be logged into your mysql server)

```
mysqldump -hlocalhost -u<root> -p<password>  <dbname>  --compact --no-data > </path_to_mydump/>mysql.dmp
```

Comment: I like this, it gives the create statements.

Answer (score 10):

You can pick any one of the command below. All of them are more or less same:

`SHOW CREATE TABLE TABLE_NAME;`

`DESC TABLE_NAME;`

`SHOW FULL COLUMNS FROM TABLE_NAME;` *(for column properties)*

`EXPLAIN TABLE_NAME;`

`DESCRIBE TABLE_NAME;`

Answer (score 4):

In the following example,

> **`playground`** is the database name and **`equipment`** is the table name

Another way is using [SHOW-COLUMNS:5.5](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/show-columns.html) (available also for `5.5>`)

```
$ mysql -uroot -p<password> -h<host> -P<port> -e \
    "SHOW COLUMNS FROM playground.equipment"
```

And the output:

```
mysql: [Warning] Using a password on the command line interface can be insecure.
+-------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id    | int(11)     | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| type  | varchar(50) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| quant | int(11)     | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| color | varchar(25) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+-------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

One can also use [mysqlshow-client](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysqlshow.html) (also available for `5.5>`) like following:

```
$ mysqlshow -uroot -p<password> -h<host> -P<port> \
    playground equipment
```

And the output:

```
mysqlshow: [Warning] Using a password on the command line interface can be insecure.
Database: playground  Table: equipment
+-------+-------------+-------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+---------------------------------+---------+
| Field | Type        | Collation         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          | Privileges                      | Comment |
+-------+-------------+-------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+---------------------------------+---------+
| id    | int(11)     |                   | NO   | PRI |         | auto_increment | select,insert,update,references |         |
| type  | varchar(50) | latin1_swedish_ci | YES  |     |         |                | select,insert,update,references |         |
| quant | int(11)     |                   | YES  |     |         |                | select,insert,update,references |         |
| color | varchar(25) | latin1_swedish_ci | YES  |     |         |                | select,insert,update,references |         |
+-------+-------------+-------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+---------------------------------+---------+
```

Answer (score 3):

SELECT `COLUMN_NAME` 
FROM `INFORMATION_SCHEMA`.`COLUMNS` 
WHERE `TABLE_SCHEMA`='bodb' 
    AND `TABLE_NAME`='abc';

works for getting all column names

Answer (score 1):

Nowadays, people use `DESC` instead of `DESCRIPTION`. For example:-
`DESC users;`