# how to get table structure as an SQL query in phpmyadmin

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, table-structure, describe

I have many tables in my MySQL database & I want to know the table structure of all tables.

When I type `desc tableName` in SQL Column I see the table structure in tabular format. How can I get the table structure in SQL query format as we normally see?

---

### Answer

I found answer in below link.

https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/15537/how-to-display-database-structure-in-phpmyadmin

Comment: ***@CloseVotersForDuplicate :*** **This is not duplicate of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/898688/how-to-get-database-structure-in-mysql-via-query) because if you write `DESCRIBE table;` in phpMyAdmin, you will get table structure in tabular format and not in the query format how we get on command prompt...**

Comment: Related, if it's of interest, I wrote a *Describe All Tables* in [this Answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38679580). You could mess with the output you are looking for (for instance, don't have it call the 2nd stored proc by having parameter #4 being FALSE).

Answer (score 2):

Do you mean:

```
desc TABLENAME\G;
```

Comment: \g does nothing different from desc TABLENAME; but \G formats the output differently. Just try it and see if it's what you need.

Comment: **desc company_details \G** gives syntax error...

Comment: Yup what @FahimParkar indicated, that appended `\G` gave me an error as well: `You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '\G' at line 1`

Comment: Got error:  #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '\G' at line 1

Comment: @Mystery - without really wanting to resurrect a necro thread, this might help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45878588/unable-to-describe-table-error-1064-42000-you-have-an-error-in-your-sql-synt

Answer (score 0):

Or you can,

```
SHOW COLUMNS FROM ``MyDataBase`.`MyTables` WHERE IN
( SELECT TABLE_NAME FROM information_schema.TABLES WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'MyDataBase' );
```