# Unable to describe table, ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax

Tags: mysql, database, relational-database

I have database with numerous tables, one of them called group is created by code:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `sc`.`group` (
  `id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `description` TEXT NULL,
  `group_type_id` INT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_group_group_type1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`group_type_id`)
    REFERENCES `sc`.`group_type` (`id`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;

CREATE INDEX `fk_group_group_type1_idx` ON `sc`.`group` (`group_type_id` ASC);
```

When I use command show tables, I got:

```
+-------------------------------------+
| event_type                          |
| function                            |
| group                               |
| group_admin                         |
...
...
+-------------------------------------+
```

If I for example write: `describe function;`, the mysql returns:

```
+-------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id    | int(11)     | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| name  | varchar(45) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+-------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

But if I write `describe group;` I get an error: 
`ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'group' at line 1`

I can't do any operation (e.g. select, insert) on `group` table.

What is wrong with it?

Comment: Group isn't a great name for a table (think group by). If you must then  qualify all references with back ticks (as you did in the create statement).

Comment: @P.Salmon you are righte, `describe \`group\`;`  works

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You create the table using quotes (I think because group is a reserved word)

Try

```
DESCRIBE `group`;
```

Comment: Tip: avoid anyway to use table names as reserved words.  And avoid (if possible) to use quoted names.

Comment: I was not able to run this command though the `table name` was `student` and i was also getting same error 1064. Reconnecting to mysql worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Group is a reserved keyword in MySql. You need to use backticks in the describe statement.

Please try the following command:

> describe `group`;

Please avoid using reserved keywords for table and column names. You can add prefix to your table name like tbl_group.