# How to get some extra info description of a mysql table

Tags: c#, mysql

I found in stackoverflow a [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/898688/how-to-get-database-structure-in-mysql-via-query) who explains this question. I wrote a procedure who does that but the retreived data is not as it's expected by mysql

Here is data that I receive using  procedure (this gives an error when I use it for creating a table in this form, the error is syntax error near `id` int(11))

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `atelier`( 
`id`  int(11) NO PRI  auto_increment
`nom`  varchar(30) NO UNI  
`at_date`  date NO   
`pax`  int(11) NO   
`prix`  double NO   
`vente`  double YES   
`note`  varchar(200) YES   
`cr_user`  varchar(15) NO   
`cr_date`  datetime NO   
`up_user`  varchar(15) YES   
`up_date`  datetime YES
```

And here is the data given by phpmyadmin

```
CREATE TABLE `Atelier` (
`id` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
`nom` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
`date` date NOT NULL,
`pax` int(11) NOT NULL,
`prix` double NOT NULL,
`vente` double default NULL,
`note` varchar(200) default NULL,
`cr_user` varchar(15) NOT NULL,
`cr_date` datetime NOT NULL,
`up_user` varchar(15) default NULL,
`up_date` datetime default NULL,
PRIMARY KEY  (`id`)
) ENGINE=Innodb DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;
```

What I want to know should I do translation of YES AND NO within my program or there is a way to obtain it with a query,  and with wich query I can obtain info of two last lines given by phpmyadmin.(I think they are usefull for the choose of ENGINE and define the unique and primary keys)

PS:Using c#, and names of the tables I get from another procedure that exist in my program. I don't get it with DESCRIBE. What I receive is between id and up_date.

Here is the link of my procedures [MY PROCEDURES](http://www.turcguide.com/stack/readingschemas.txt)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't show the procedure generating this output, but if you replace `DESCRIBE` in there with `SHOW CREATE TABLE` I suppose it will work.

Comment: I updated and added to MY PROCEDURES link, and I'm just trying your suggestion

Comment: Thanks I get with SHOW CREATE TABLE whole data as given by phpmyadmin. I have some errors but it's about formatting.

Comment: I changed the procedure as the needs of SHOW CREATE TABLE. It works perfectly. And I changed my link with new for those who look for that solution