# The columns are added to the listbox1 from the entire database for some reason, although only needed from the Students table

Tags: c#, mysql

The columns are added to the listbox1 from the entire database for some reason, although only needed from the Students table

```
MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand("SELECT * FROM Students", sqlConnection);
try
{
    await command.ExecuteNonQueryAsync();
    DataTable schema = sqlConnection.GetSchema("Columns");
    foreach (DataRow row in schema.Rows)
    {
        listBox1.Items.Add(row.Field<string>("COLUMN_NAME"));
    }
}
```

Comment: names of the columns

Comment: You probably want to [query the INFORMATION_SCHEMA table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/898688/).

Comment: pls help me. What need to edit and add

Comment: GetSchema is not using the results from the query.  I just is going straight into the database and getting everything.

Comment: @jdweng how to fix?

Answer (score 1):

```
try
{
    string[] restrictions = new string[4] { null, null, "Students", null };
    DataTable schema = sqlConnection.GetSchema("Columns", restrictions); 
    foreach (DataRow row in schema.Rows)
    {
        listBox1.Items.Add(row.Field<string>("COLUMN_NAME"));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try following :

```
try
{
    MySqlDataAdapter adapter = new MySqlDataAdapter(command);
    DataTable students = new DataTable();
    adapter.Fill(students);
    foreach(DataColumn col in students.Columns)
    {
        listBox1.Items.Add(col.ColumnName);
    }
}
```