# Convert all the mysql table data into JSON in spring boot

Tags: mysql, json, spring

I want to just specify the table name and it will automatically convert all of its data to JSON Format

I have tried a code that is storing the data from table into JSON using JDBC .

```
public class DataBaseToJson {
    public static ResultSet RetrieveData() throws Exception {
        DriverManager.registerDriver(new com.mysql.jdbc.Driver());
        String mysqlUrl = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/studentsDB?autoReconnect=true&useSSL=false";
        Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(mysqlUrl, "root", "root");
        Statement statement = con.createStatement();
        ResultSet resultSet = statement.executeQuery("Select * from students");
        return resultSet;
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
        JSONArray array = new JSONArray();
        ResultSet resultSet = RetrieveData();
        while (resultSet.next()) {
            JSONObject record = new JSONObject();
            record.put("students ID", resultSet.getInt("students_id"));
            record.put("students Name", resultSet.getString("students_name"));
            array.add(record);
        }
        jsonObject.put("students Information", array);
        try {
            FileWriter file = new FileWriter("output.json");
            file.write(jsonObject.toJSONString());
            file.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

I don't want to specify the fileds in a file. I want to make it generic so that we could only put the table name and it will automatically convert all the data from that table and save into a JSON file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
        String tableName = "books";
        Connection connection = createConnection();
        JSONArray array = new JSONArray();
        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
        List<String> columns = loadColumns(connection, tableName);
        ResultSet dataSet = loadData(connection, tableName);
        while (dataSet.next()) {
            JSONObject record = new JSONObject();
            for (String column : columns) {
                record.put(column, dataSet.getObject(column));
            }
            array.add(record);
        }
        jsonObject.put(tableName, array);
        try {
            FileWriter file = new FileWriter("output.json");
            file.write(jsonObject.toJSONString());
            file.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private static Connection createConnection() throws SQLException {
        DriverManager.registerDriver(new com.mysql.jdbc.Driver());
        String mysqlUrl = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/library?autoReconnect=true&useSSL=false";
        Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(mysqlUrl, "root", "root");
        return connection;
    }


    public static List<String> loadColumns(Connection connection, String tableName) throws SQLException {
        Statement statement = connection.createStatement();
        ResultSet resultSet = statement.executeQuery("SELECT COLUMN_NAME FROM `INFORMATION_SCHEMA`.`COLUMNS` WHERE TABLE_NAME LIKE '"+tableName+"'");
        List<String> columnsName = new ArrayList<String>();
        while(resultSet.next()) {
            columnsName.add(resultSet.getString("COLUMN_NAME"));
        }
        return columnsName;
    }

    public static ResultSet loadData(Connection connection, String tableName) throws SQLException {
        Statement statement = connection.createStatement();
        ResultSet resultSet = statement.executeQuery("Select * from "+tableName+"");
        return resultSet;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can select list of columns for given table using `INFORMATION_SCHEMA`:

```
SELECT COLUMN_NAME FROM `INFORMATION_SCHEMA`.`COLUMNS` WHERE TABLE_NAME LIKE 'table_name'
```

Now, convert `ResultSet` from above query to `List<String>` of column names. After that we can use it to convert final `ResultSet` to `JSON Object`.

Pseudocode:

```
Connection connection = createConnection();
List<String> columns = loadColumns(connection, tableName);
ResultSet dataSet = loadData(connection, tableName);
while (dataSet.next()) {
    JSONObject record = new JSONObject();
    for (String column : columns) {
        record.put(column, dataSet.getObject(column));
    }
    array.add(record);
}
// save array to file
```

When `ResultSet` is huge we should consider to use `Streaming API` from `Jackson` or `Gson` libraries to avoid "out of memory" problem.

See also:

- [How to get database structure in MySQL via query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/898688/how-to-get-database-structure-in-mysql-via-query)
- [Jackson Streaming API](https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-streaming-api)
- [Jackson - Processing model: Streaming API](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-docs/wiki/JacksonStreamingApi)
- [Gson Streaming](https://sites.google.com/site/gson/streaming)

### Update

It looks like we do not event need to select column names using extra `SQL` query because `ResultSet` has [getMetaData](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#getMetaData()) method:

> Retrieves the number, types and properties of this ResultSet object's
>   columns.

See also:

- [ResultSetMetaData class](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSetMetaData.html)

Comment: Ziober this is showing "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException" at **foreach loop** .

Comment: as per your SQL query we are able to get the name of columns  but not the data in these columns. Please specify the way in which we could get the columns and data automatically and than simply stored this data as JSON

Comment: @RaoWaqasAkram, It is a good start. You need to execute two `SQL` queries. First query is what I shown in answer - load all columns for a given table. Convert result set to list of column names. After that execute second `SQL` query which loads real data - `Select * from table_name`. Now you can convert `ResultSet` to `JSON Object` using column names.

Comment: sir could you please update your answer as per requirement . I am highly thankful to you.

Comment: @RaoWaqasAkram, I noticed in documentation that we have already all required info about columns using `getMetaData` method. You can improve your solution by using it. We can avoid one extra call to DB. It is not big mistake to do that in small applications but if you need to call this code very often you can use this method. I'm glad to see you found a way to implement this.

Comment: sir i found one error . : org.json.JSONException: Expected a ',' or ']' at 57 [character 58 line 1] .

Comment: @RaoWaqasAkram, you should not use `org.json` library if you already use `Jackson`. Probably this error is not related with that problem. In case you do not know how to solve it, create a new question.