# parsing huge amount JSON data from file into JAVA object that cause out of heap memory Exception

Tags: json, parsing, jackson, gson, out-of-memory

I have 200mb of JSON data and I want to parse that JSON data into JAVA(MAP, JSONObject, not any POJO).
I had used GSON and Jackson both library but both are giving me an error.

Comment: Can you share your errors with me, please?

Comment: 200 MB is not a huge data file. Take a look at: [How to deserialise big JSON file (~300Mb)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58726892/how-to-deserialise-big-json-file-300mb), [Convert all the mysql table data into JSON in spring boot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58772409/convert-all-the-mysql-table-data-into-json-in-spring-boot), [how to parse a huge JSON file without loading it in memory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54817985/how-to-parse-a-huge-json-file-without-loading-it-in-memory)

Comment: Thanks @MichałZiober The solutions seem good. [How to deserialise big JSON file (~300Mb)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58726892/how-to-deserialise-big-json-file-300mb) is may help me a lot.

Comment: Have you solved this problem? Did linked questions were helpful?

Comment: @MichałZiober Yes, I resolved the problem with that solutions

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to deserialise big JSON file (~300Mb)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58726892/how-to-deserialise-big-json-file-300mb). I marked your question as duplicate. You can upvote related answers which helped you.